# Narrow facets when having different number of variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I get a wider facet for the facet that only contains one variable on the x-axis. It is getting to narrow.

```
ggplot(df,aes(V1)) + geom_histogram(stat="count") + facet_grid(~Class, scales="free_x", space="free")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 8) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size=5))
```

[image]

Comment: remove the `space = "free` argument form `facet_grid()` If you need more precise control of individual facet width, you will have to rely on `geom_blank()`

Comment: Please add some reproducible data to your question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example